# Monitor sound output option disappeared [UPDATED]

Tags: windows-10, audio, multiple-monitors, nvidia, hp

I have a double monitor setup in Windows 10 Pro. An AOC monitor (DP) and an HP E243m (HDMI).

I've always had 4 output options: monitor AOC, two options for monitor HP (all NVIDIA) and headset (Realtek (R) Audio).

Previously, my output option was "HP E243m Echo Cancellation (NVIDIA High Definition Audio)". For this specific monitor, I've always had two output options on the Windows 10 output device selection. I've had that one that I mentioned and one without the "Echo Cancellation" part. Only the "Echo Cancellation" option would output sound.

Recentely, this "HP E243m Echo Cancellation (NVIDIA High Definition Audio)" was simply gone. I have no idea why. I still have the other output option for this monitor, "HP E243m (NVIDIA High Definition Audio)", but this option, like stated before, produces no sound.

On the sound control panel, the option is also gone.

Here is what I've tried:

- Re-install Geforce Drivers
- Device Manager -> Update all sound and NVIDIA related drivers
- Rebooted (several times)
- Device Manager -> Scan for hardwre changes
- Disconnect and reconnect the monitor's HDMI cable
- Turn the monitor OFF and ON again

Update of what I've tried:

- Swaped the HDMI cable and rebooted. Same result. Only one output option.
- Tried using the other HDMI port of the graphics card

Update of what I've found:

- Can't upgrade the firmware. Tried with 3 different HDMI cables and get the error mesage: "HP E243m Monitor device not found".

Please, tell me if you've experienced this issue before and what you've done to fix it, or sugest a possible solution, please. Thanks in advance.

[!!UPDATE!!]

So a few months have passed and... somehow someway the output options are back.

I did not installed or uninstalled anything in the mean time. Firmware update does work now. I have no clue what caused the problem and what cause the respective solution. It's worth to state that it's not 100% working, because before this happened, the two sound output options used to play the sound a bit diferentely, and now it's the same. If anyone has any clues on this, please share. Thanks.

Comment: You might try checking your HDMI cable, the connectors and the monitor firmware. I believe this is the [last firmware version](https://support.hp.com/vn-en/document/c07636296).

Comment: Yeah, definitely would try a different hdmi cable that you know works, just to rule out that its not a faulty HDMI cable. Also, you can try that cable on another computer that you know should work.

Comment: @LPChip I've updated the question. Unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: @harrymc Tried 3 different cables and with all of the I get the error message (while trying to update the firmware): "HP E243m Monitor device not found". So that's a starting point. I will troubleshoot further. Thanks.

Comment: I don't like the error message of "Monitor device not found". How old is the monitor (it came out in 2017)?

Comment: @harrymc I got it brand new last year, worked fine ever since until now!

Comment: The way to find out is to try this monitor on another computer. If the same thing happens, then the problem is with it and not with the computer.

Comment: @harrymc Just did that with my work PC. Tested different cables too. The same error message pops up. Definitely something wrong with the monitor and not the system. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing the monitor on another computer and with several HDMI cables
gave the same results - no sound.
Also, the monitor's firmware update utility doesn't manage to identify
this monitor.

Taken together, the conclusion is that the monitor has developed
a hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to chime in and say that this insane behavior has happened to me as well. From one day to another, it changed the name of the output and just stopped producing sound.
Firmware update: same error.

Thanks for any more info on this!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).